# Как удалить неканоническую страницу из поиска в Тильде

Tags: оптимизация, индексация, tilda

Сайт на Тильде. В поиск попали такого рода страницы:

```
https://mysyte.ru/shop?tfc_storepartuid[374766152]=%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B&tfc_div=:::
```

Обычно для запрета индексации в `robots.txt`   добавляется

```
Disallow: /shop?
```

но что делать на Тильде я не знаю, поскольку нет доступа к роботс.

Добавлю, что эту страницу https://mysyte.ru/shop я сделал канонической в надежде, что остальные исчезнут из поиска, но не получилось.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться